# SCALA-IDE: Eclipse highlight matching variables / mark occurrences extremely slow

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I just installed the SCALA-IDE plugin and the highlighting in it is excruciatingly slow (circa 1 minute on a 1k-line file) rendering it useless. Meanwhile, the same Eclipse session with the PyDev plugin still works within about a second on very large files.

I was wondering if there was a way to speed it up?